# Need to create a report which shows the most recent order for each customer, in each month, within the last year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to `SQL server` so I apologize if this is considered n easy question.

I'm using the tables `sales.orders`, `sales.customers` from the sample `TSQL 2012 database`.

I know this is wrong but so far I've only been able to string together

```
SELECT cust.custid, ord.orderid, ord.orderdate
FROM sales.customers as cust
INNER JOIN sales.orders as ord ON (ord.custid=cust.custid)
AND ord.orderid = (SELECT TOP 1 ord.orderid
                FROM sales.orders
                WHERE cust.custid=ord.custid 
                ORDER BY ord.orderdate DESC);
```

I feel like I should be using MAX someone in the subquery but I don't know how to write it in order to get

1. the most recent item per each customer
2. within each month.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of query, I prefer to use the ranking functions, `row_number` in particular.  The following query identifies the most recent order per month for each customer using seqnum, and then selects this:

```
select cust.custid, ord.orderid, ord.orderdate
from sales.customers cust INNER JOIN
     (select o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by custid, yr, mon order by orderdate desc) as seqnum
      from (select o.*, YEAR(o.orderdate) as yr, MONTH(o.orderdate) as mon
            from sales.orders o
           )
     ) ord
     on cust.custid = ord.custid and
        ord.seqnum = 1
```

Your version of the query did not take the month into account.